# Delete Row in Tableview and data remove on database using Sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am developing IOS App, using `Sqlite` to Store data. Data can be shown on `tableview` and delete the row from table view and data can be remove form database `sqlite`. but when I delete row from `tableview`, app is crashing. And the error I am getting is :

> Error:reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. 
>   The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
>   (9) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
>   before the update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or
>   deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus
>   the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0
>   moved out).

Thanks in Advance

Code :

```
    NSMutableArray *resultArray

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    dataBase *data = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    name.text = data.name;
    UILabel *department = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    department.text = data.department;
    UILabel *year = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    year.text = data.year;

    if (indexPath.row %2 ==1)   //Use for color on tableview
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.9 blue:.9 alpha:1];
    else
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.8 green:.8 blue:.8 alpha:1];
   return cell;
}
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            [_tableView beginUpdates];

            Sqlite *sqlite = [[Sqlite alloc]init];
            [sqlite delete_profile:indexPath.row];

            NSMutableArray *newA = [[sqlite resultArray] mutableCopy];
            [newA removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            [_tableView endUpdates];
        }
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }

   // Method to delete Row From Sqlite

    -(void)delete_profile:(NSInteger)value
    {
        //      _categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSString *databasename=@"student.db";  // Your database Name.

        NSArray * documentpath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);

        NSString * DocDir=[documentpath objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",DocDir);
        NSString * databasepath=[DocDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databasename];


        if (sqlite3_open([databasepath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSStringEncoding stringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
            NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM studentsDetail WHERE regno=\"%ld\"",(long)value];
            const char *sqlStatement = [sql cStringUsingEncoding:stringEncoding];
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                                   sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, value);

                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    dataBase *base = [[dataBase alloc]init];
                    base.name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                    base.department = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                    base.year = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                    [_resultArray addObject:base];
                }
            }
            else {
                NSAssert1(0,@"Error preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give me your tableview Datasourse array name

Comment: NSMutableArray *resultArray

Comment: show your `numberOfRowsInSection`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods !

Comment: Can you please post the error log here

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (9) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Comment: put cellForRowAtIndexPath methods.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `[_tableView reloadData]`; after `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` 
Try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

            Sqlite *sqlite = [[Sqlite alloc]init];
            [sqlite delete_profile:indexPath.row];

            [resultArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

     }

}
```

Comment: `Sqlite *sqlite = [[Sqlite alloc]init];` Are you serious?

Comment: i am not sure that he is using singleton petten of Sqlite class